# SQLite Getting only last record not all the Records

Tags: android, sqlite, join, left-join

I have total **4 records** in *ecare* table, where `2 records` status is **sent = 1**, and other *2 records* status is `sent = 0`

**RECORDS**

```
1st Record : Track 1 [sent = 1]

2nd Record : Track 2 [sent = 1]

3rd Record : Track 3 [sent = 0]

4th Record : Track 4 [sent = 0]
```

But getting only *last* record (i.e. - **Track 4**) not *all two* records those status is **sent = 0**

Here is the SQLite query, which I am using to fetch data from database

```
public synchronized List<String> getECareData() {

        String sql = "SELECT p.sent,e.*, e.no _id from ecare e LEFT JOIN pweb p ON e.h_id=p.h_id WHERE p.sent = '0' GROUP BY e.h_id";

        List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            records.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
        return records;
    }
```

**UPDATED**

```
 public synchronized List<String> getECareData() {

    String sql = "SELECT p.sent,e.*, e.no _id from ecare e LEFT JOIN pweb p ON e.h_id=p.h_id WHERE p.sent = '0' GROUP BY e.h_id";

    List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            records.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("records:", records.toString());

    return records;
}
```

**Log says:**

```
D/records:: [Getting only LAST record here] the 4th one
```

I guess, there is something `wrong` with *query*, because I am getting only last record in **Cursor**

**UPDATED RECORDS**

```
1st Record : Track 1 [sent = 1]

2nd Record : Track 2 [sent = 1]

3rd Record : Track 3 [sent = 0]

4th Record : Track 4 [sent = 0]

5th Record : Track 5 [sent = 0]
```

But getting only *last* record (i.e. - **Track 5**) not *all three* records those status is **sent = 0**

**Log says:**

```
D/records:: [Getting only LAST record here] the 5th one
```

**UPDATED QUERY** - Removed GROUP BY from query

And now getting each and every record, even those belongs to **sent = 1** whereas I just want to fetch data that belongs to **sent = 0** only

```
String sql = "SELECT p.sent,e.*, e.no _id from ecare e LEFT JOIN pweb p ON e.h_id=p.h_id WHERE p.sent = '0' ";
```

Comment: Do cursor.moveToFirst() before your while loop.

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN p... WHERE p...` is the same as `INNER JOIN p`

Comment: @ayeshdon See UPDATED section, but  still getting last record only, not both the records

Comment: @Strawberry please check my UPDATED code, still getting one and only last record

Comment: Debug and check how many records you are getting in cursor. Might be your query will also wrong.

Comment: A simple `moveToNext()` loop is perfectly fine. Show the *actual* data in the tables.

Comment: Not that you're likely to pay much attention to anything that's actually said here, but generally, in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate.

Comment: @Strawberry exactly where I am doing mistake please check updated code and records I posted above

Comment: Run your query as is in a sqlite editor (with your tables and data) and see if it gives you the right data. If yes, then add the moveToFirst() (doesnt really matter since moveToNext() should do) and check, because unless there is some issue with the data (character codes?). Seperate out cursor.getString(0) and fetch it in a variable so you can debug if it's getting data. This should be solvable by simply debugging correctly

Comment: @Oreo why not use **ORDER BY** (**ASC** or **DESC**) _track_ _number_ or whatever let you know what entry came last?

Comment: i think problem for your query section

Answer (score 3):

Your missing `startManagingCursor()` method.

```
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
  cursor.getCount();
  startManagingCursor(cursor);//the important line
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      if(cursor.getCount() == 0)
      {
           //error no records
      }
      else
      {
      for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
      {
              records.add(cursor.getString(0));
          adapter.add(aString);
          cursor.moveToNext();
      }
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      }
```

**NOTE:**
`startManagingCursor()` is deprecated because it does operations on the main thread which can freeze up the UI and deliver a poor user experience. You should use a `CursorLoader` with a `LoaderManager` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
String sql = "SELECT p.sent,e.*, e.no _id 
              FROM ecare e, pweb p 
              WHERE e.h_id=p.h_id 
              AND e.sent = '0' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to re-create your database, is this right, what is the problem, seems to work.

```
CREATE TABLE ecare (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,h_id  INTEGER ,no  INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE pweb (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,h_id  INTEGER ,sent  INTEGER);
sqlite> insert into ecare values(1, 10,1);
sqlite> insert into ecare values(2, 20,2);
sqlite> insert into ecare values(3, 30,3);
sqlite> insert into ecare values(4, 40,4);
sqlite>
sqlite> insert into pweb values(1, 10,1);
sqlite> insert into pweb values(2, 20,1);
sqlite> insert into pweb values(3, 30,0);
sqlite> insert into pweb values(4, 40,0);
sqlite> select * from ecare;
1|10|1
2|20|2
3|30|3
4|40|4
sqlite> select * from pweb;
1|10|1
2|20|1
3|30|0
4|40|0
sqlite> SELECT p.sent,e.*, e.no _id from ecare e LEFT JOIN pweb p ON e.h_id=p.h_id WHERE p.sent = '0';
0|3|30|3|3
0|4|40|4|4
sqlite>
```